# meu h2 e h3 fica na mesma linha que o paragrafo

Tags: html, css

Quero colocar o H2 em cima e o Paragrafo embaixo, e na sessão de contato quero colocar o H3 > H2 > Conteudo (Nessa ordem), porém, meu parágrafo fica lado a lado com o título

```css
section .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 60px;
}

section img {
    height: 350px;
}
```

```html
    <section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <img class="facade" src="images/fachada.jpg" alt="Fachada loja Balearic Properties">
              <h2>Sobre Nós</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit in non, aspernatur dolore eius blanditiis, tempore nostrum veritatis animi voluptatem expedita accusantium perferendis et officiis soluta dolorem ducimus, odio amet?
                <br>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum tempora in distinctio, quibusdam eius est impeditsimilique. Repellendus veniam mollitia optio, illo autem eveniet aliquam labore fugiat incidunt earum esse?
                </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contato</h2>
            <div class="contact-methods">
                <h3>Fale Conosco</h3>
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Seu telefone (opcional)">
                    <textarea placeholder="Sua mensagem" required></textarea>
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Nos Acompanhe</h3>
                <ul class="social-media">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Logo do Facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/instagram.png" alt="Logo do Instagram"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/whatsapp.png" alt="Logo do Whatsapp"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score -3):

Olá! Estou aqui para te ajudar, eu fiz o código certo para ***você***! 
Eu ***formatei*** o seu HTML e fiz ***mudanças*** que até seus botões mudaram.

O HTML está aqui!

```css
/* Os estilos estão no HTML */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://lucasjoao.w3spaces.com/resetcss/importanresefset.css" defer/>
      <!-- 
         Seu site ficara sem alguns bugs ao colocar o estilo aqui, ele não mudara nada
         -->
      <style>
         /* Para ficar mais bonito, uso o bonificador meu */
         body{
         margin: 0;
         padding: 8px;
         font-family:system-ui, apple-system, Segoe UI, Apple Color Emoji, Roboto, Arial, Noto, Noto Sans, sans-serif;
         }
         section .container {
         justify-content: space-between;
         margin-left: 99px;
         padding-left: 100px;
         }
         section img {
         height: 350px;
         }
         [data-inline]{
         display: inline;
         position: relative;
         }
         /* https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed2 */
         .sidenav {
         width: 130px;
         z-index: 1;
         top: 20px;
         left: 10px;
         background: #eee;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         padding: 8px 0;
         position: fixed;
         border-radius:1em;
         }
         .main {
         margin-left: 140px; /* Same width as the sidebar + left position in px */
         font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
         }
         @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
         .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
         .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
         }
         /*====== 2
         *https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_alert_buttons*/
         .btn {
         border: none;
         color: white;
         padding: 14px 28px;
         font-size: 16px;
         cursor: pointer;
         transition:.333s;
         border-radius:1em;
         }
         .btn.default {background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black;} /* Gray */ 
         .btn.default:hover {background: #ddd;}
         /*====*/
         .social-media{
         list-style-type: none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="sidenav">
         <img class="facade" src="images/fachada.jpg" alt="Fachada loja Balearic Properties"><br/>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div id="main">
         <section id="about">
            <div class="container">
               <h2 data-inline>Sobre Nós</h2>
               <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit in non, aspernatur dolore eius blanditiis, tempore nostrum veritatis animi voluptatem expedita accusantium perferendis et officiis soluta dolorem ducimus, odio amet?
                  <br>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum tempora in distinctio, quibusdam eius est impeditsimilique. Repellendus veniam mollitia optio, illo autem eveniet aliquam labore fugiat incidunt earum esse?
               </p>
            </div>
         </section>
         <section id="contact">
            <div class="container">
               <h2>Contato</h2>
               <div class="contact-methods">
                  <h3>Fale Conosco</h3>
                  <form action="">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" required unselectable="on">
                     <br/>
                     <input type="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required unselectable="on">
                     <br/>
                     <input type="tel" placeholder="Seu telefone (opcional)" unselectable="on">
                     <br/>
                     <textarea placeholder="Sua mensagem" required unselectable="on"></textarea>
                     <br/>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn default">Entrar ao Contato</button>
                  </form>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <h3>Nos Acompanhe</h3>
                  <ul class="social-media">
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Logo do Facebook"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/instagram.png" alt="Logo do Instagram"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/whatsapp.png" alt="Logo do Whatsapp"></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```